# Name error data is not defined when sending POST request values from react to flask

Tags: python-3.x, reactjs, flask

I am trying to make a simple form which sends data from the client side to the server side using react and flask.

I want to be able to print the username value it gets from the form data however I am getting a NameError: 'data' is not defined.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thomashunt/app/api/app.py", line 9, in <module>
    print (data)
NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

Form:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
  
     handleSubmit(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       const data = new FormData(event.target);
      
      fetch('/api', {
         method: 'POST',
         body: data,
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Accept': 'application/json'
       });
     }
  
    render() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="username">Enter username</label>
          <input id="username" name="username" type="text" />
  
          <label htmlFor="email">Enter your email</label>
          <input id="email" name="email" type="email" />
  
          <label htmlFor="birthdate">Enter your birth date</label>
          <input id="birthdate" name="birthdate" type="text" />
  
          <button>Send data!</button>
        </form>
      );
    }
  }

  export default Form
```

App.py (server)

```
from flask import Flask, request, json


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api', methods=['GET','POST'])
def api():
        data = request.form['username']
print (data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the indentation. The `print(data)` should be indented. The variable `data` is defined inside the function `api` but called from outside.

Try this code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, json

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/api', methods=['GET','POST'])
def api():
        data = request.form['username']
        print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is showing because you are not following proper indentation while printing data.
As printing it without indentation you lose the scope of api() method, outside which data is not defined.

So to correct it --

```
from flask import Flask, request, json


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api', methods=['GET','POST'])
def api():
        data = request.form['username']
        print (data)
```